# Sqlite WHERE IN AND MATCH query

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite virtual table (fts4) for open text search. I am trying to combine `WHERE IN` and `MATCH` to get my desired results. But the problem is that I am getting an error `Error: database disk image is malformed`. Here is my sqlite query.

```
SELECT rowid,* FROM Alldata where FileMD5 IN ('9A9D70D3E2FF9388101EDF37EE87431A','A072C94BF828792D91052546C59D005B','A366E8C244D8DB0616900A61E5D90775') AND AllData MATCH 'contemporary*' limit 1000"
```

Comment: Did you ever try searching for the error message?

Comment: I know what the error is. My db is all good. I think there is some problem is with query.

Comment: Why do you think that the DB is good when the only evidence you have says the opposite?